# Ambient temperature sensor on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm developing an app for the watch, and I'm trying to implement a listener for the temperature sensor that comes on it, but it's not listed when I make the request to list all sensors.  obs I have already implemented heart rate and pedometer features and both work perfectly...is there any possibility that the android system does not recognize the temperature sensor that comes in it?  I believe it is not a permission as I have already implemented the permission for body sensors.

```
private var sensorManager: SensorManager? = null
private var sensorThermometer: Sensor? = null
private val TAG ="thermometerService"

override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Log.d(TAG, " ----------- > SERVICE ACTIVATE <--------------------")
    val deviceSensors = sensorManager!!.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL)
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand:${deviceSensors} ")
    sensorThermometer = sensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE)
    sensorManager?.let {
        Log.d(TAG, "sensor manager is not null")
    }
    sensorManager?.registerListener(this, sensorThermometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)

    return START_STICKY
}

override fun onSensorChanged(sensorEvent: SensorEvent?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "any event has onSensorDetect detect !!!")

    sensorEvent?.let {
        Log.d(TAG, "try show any value : ${sensorEvent.values[0]}")
    }
}

override fun onAccuracyChanged(p0: Sensor?, p1: Int) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged: any thing detect")
    p0?.let {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged: any value --> ${p0.name}  ")
    }
}
```

this is my service that is trying to run the temperature sensor.

these are the sensors that are listed ->

[{Sensor name="QST QMAX981 3-axis Accelerometer", vendor="QST", version=1, type=1, maxRange=19.6133, resolution=0.009576807, power=0.145, minDelay=5000}, {Sensor name="ICM206XX 3-axis Gyroscope sensor", vendor="TDK-Invensense", version=1, type=4, maxRange=34.906586, resolution=0.0, power=4.0, minDelay=10000}, {Sensor name="gh30x_sensor", vendor="Goodix", version=1, type=21, maxRange=500.0, resolution=0.1, power=0.5, minDelay=0}, {Sensor name="Game Rotation Vector Sensor", vendor="AOSP", version=3, type=15, maxRange=1.0, resolution=5.9604645E-8, power=4.145, minDelay=5000}, {Sensor name="Gravity Sensor", vendor="AOSP", version=3, type=9, maxRange=19.6133, resolution=0.009576807, power=4.145, minDelay=5000}]

I know the type of temperature sensor would be 13, but physically it's easy to see its temperature sensor outside the device.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a code snippet of how you are obtaining the sensors, and which model of watch you are developing on.

Comment: Hello Friend! I just edited my problem along with its code snippet. about the model it is not yet available on the market...